# My ajax request response hangs my firefox browser?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created dependable dropdown for country state and city using ajax in php. 
If I run it in Chrome or Opera it's working, but if I run it in Firefox the browser hangs

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#country').on('change',function(){
      var country_id=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/get_state.php',
            data:{country_id:country_id},
            success:function(data){
              $('#state').html(data);
            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });
      });

  $('#state').on('change',function(){
  var state_id=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'ajax/get_city.php',
      data:{state_id:state_id},
      success:function(data){
            $('#city').html(data);
          },
          error:function(){

          }
      });
    });
});
```

here is get_state.php :-

```
<?php

include '../config.php';
if(isset($_POST['country_id'])){
  $sql = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM states where country_id = '".$_POST['country_id']."'") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));

?>
<option value="0">Select State</option>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";

}

}

?>
```

and here is get_city.php :-

```
<?php

include '../config.php';
if(isset($_POST['state_id'])){

$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM cities where state_id = '".$_POST['state_id']."'") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));

?>
<option value="0">Select City</option>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";

}

}

?>
```

here is my ajax and all ajax php code.  This code working fine in other browser but if i run in Firefox so Firefox hang.

Comment: i try that but it's still not fix my issue.

Comment: did you try also this line? ` e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Set debug points to see where it loops ?

Comment: yes i add also e.e.preventDefault();@pr1nc3

Comment: Please tag appropriately & carefully. This seems to have nothing whatsoever to do with what the `j` tag stands for.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: have you tried to use the browser tools in Firefox to check for errors either in the JavaScript (look in the Console) or in the ajax calls (look in the Console and also the Network tools)? Just saying it doesn't work is not much help to anyone...you need to do some debugging work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> change your code with this code it will start working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(document).on('change','#country',function(){
      var country_id=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/get_state.php',
            data:{country_id:country_id},
            success:function(data){
              $('#state').html(data);
            },
            error:function(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });
      });

  $(document).on('change','#state',function(){
  var state_id=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'ajax/get_city.php',
      data:{state_id:state_id},
      success:function(data){
            $('#city').html(data);
          },
          error:function(e){
            alert(e);
          }
      });
    });
});
```

i made two changes here

1. i use `$(document).ready(function(){`  instead if `$('#country').on('change',function(){`
2. and also found bug here `$('#country,').` extra comma was thare.

Comment: i do but it's still not working i already uninstall and install firefox 5 time but nothing change....now i can't understand my code is wrong or it's firefox problem....with this code chrome and opera working fine but firefox hang

Comment: have you used my code.. please push my full code so you can see changes.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro you can put one more parameter on your ajax call async: true,

Comment: `async: true` is by default set in ajax no need to include it.

Comment: yeah sure @RitulLakhtariya

Comment: @RoronoaZoro i also fix issue for js so +1 if you like that.

Comment: "change your code with this code it will start working properly." ...what did you change, and why? It's not that useful providing a code dump without explanantion, no-one will understand what is important about it.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your feedback generatlly people can compare it but let me edit it so then you can give +1 for me.

Comment: people can only compare it if they understand what the code is doing...but if they're looking for help on this topic then chances are they don't fully understand (otherwise they likely wouldn't have a problem!). Hence why an explanation is necessary for all but the most trivial examples.

Comment: @ADyson i add some more content here can you please look it out and if you think than remove this -1 .. an thanks for correct me.

Comment: can you share your code @RoronoaZoro so we can understand your problems.

Comment: i just add your code in my code...and you already see my other code in my question

Comment: Ok thanks... So: "$(document).ready(function(){ instead if $('#country').on('change',function(){" ...did you actually mean `$(document).on` ? That's what the code says. And why is that an improvement? It only helps if the dropdown is being added to the DOM dynamically, but we have no suggestion that this is what is happening. On what basis did you make that assumption?

Answer (score 2):

You should really have error handling in your ajax request. It probably isn't hanging as much as you think, but actually erroring.

Modify your empty `error: function()` lines to:

```
error: function(res)
{
    console.log(res);
}
```

in your console (**F12** on Firefox) it *should* display some debugging information for your ajax request. This will help you narrow down the problem (in which case edit your question to that specific problem).

**Note:** Not sure if this is fully classes as an answer or a comment- either way, this should address the freezing issue and help debug it further.

Answer (score 1):

Your code having a error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#country,').on('change',function(){
```

In `$('#country,')` there are extra comma.
Replace with `$('#country')`.
With that error It haven't run from any browser for me.

Comment: i remove it but my issue is not fix...i got same issue

Comment: Your js function is working correctly. Check your php code.

Answer (score 0):

> here i found some issue on your php code you just echo for each row

```
<?php

include '../config.php';
if(isset($_POST['country_id'])){
  $sql = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM states where country_id = '".$_POST['country_id']."'") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));

?>
$html .= "<option value='0'>Select State</option>";
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

$html .="<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";

}

}
echo $html;
?>
```

> you can see in your code every line you are trying to echo, generally
>   after echo  ajax call will fire success call so it will go in infinite
>
> so best practise is that store in variable `$html` and echo  in last.

i hope it will help you

Comment: "some issue"... what issue? What did you change and why? This answer has exactly the same problem with lack of information I commented on in your first one, and yet you didn't think to improve this one. And why have you posted multiple answers? If lots of things need fixing, put it all in one answer - only one answer can be the final accepted one.

Comment: @ADyson i added some more content there . thanks a lot to improve me i really like this.

Comment: "generally after echo ajax call will fire success call so it will go in infinite" ....no, that's completely and utterly untrue, and can be demonstrated with a trivial test. The Ajax client does not get any kind of response at all until the server is ready to output the whole thing. Output is not sent in parts. This is true of any HTTP response, unless flushing is explicitly enabled...but in any case ajax cannot deal with flushed responses so it can't be used even if you wanted to.

Comment: What we really need here is more detailed info from the OP, e.g. checking their browser's tools for errors, network issues etc.

Comment: P.S. the yellow highlighting on StackOverflow is intended for quoting from other sources (e.g. if you paste something from the PHP documentation perhaps), not for general text.

Comment: thanks @RitulLakhtariya for give me your time and really thanks because of your answer i really fix my problem and now my ajax run better in any browser.

Comment: why -1 can someone explaine me?